# How to waterproof a leaky front porch that has a basement room underneath?

Tags: leak

Our front porch has interlocking stone on top of the concrete. Underneath that porch is a basement cold room that has water leaking from the ceiling though the porch into that room. We have yet to get the interlocking stone removed to see if there are any cracks in the concrete porch.

What do you suggest to put on top of the concrete porch before laying the interlock back on top of it? Some contractors we called to look at the issue suggested filling any cracks and then paint the porch with water-repellent paint. We doubt that this will prevent future cracks in the cement porch from reappearing. Would some sort of waterproof membrane be a solution? If so, are there specific membranes to be used? Any other things we could do to fix this issue?

Comment: Use the tar paper used on the roofs

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/209257/18078  and https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/268845/18078

Answer (score 1):

I like torch on membrane.  It applies nicely to concrete.  It is rated for people walking on it and it lasts at least 30 years.  You can thinset or mortar on top of it.

The other option to consider is a shower liner.  The oatey pvc shower membrane can work but it depends on the area and if you can avoid seams.